# wget not working on Arch and having depdendencies to both libnettle.so.6 and libnettle.so.7

Tags: arch-linux, wget, dependencies, pacman

I think upgrading the system with `pacman -Syu` after a year of inactivity is the issue.

Now pacman can't download anything as wget won't run anymore with the following error:

> wget: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Downgrading nettle to previous version doesn't help either, as then the same error message is produced but for libnettle.so7

..Checking the wget dependencies with ldd I get to see both are defined as dependencies (libnette.so.6 and libnettle.so7) but the so.6 is not found.

`ldd /usr/bin/wget | grep libnettle
    libnettle.so.6 => not found
    libnettle.so.7 => /usr/lib/libnettle.so.7 (0x00007f8f261f6000)`

I've always been able to recover from issues caused by updating after long periods of not booting the system but this time I don't find anything. Any advice on how to fix my system would be much appreciated..

I only found this closed bug report that isn't very helpful but is 100% the same issue https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/63153

(P.S. simply symlinking to libnettle.so.7 is not doing the trick)

Comment: As a quick fix you could try to create the file as symlink: `ln -s /usr/lib/libnettle.so.7 /usr/lib/libnettle.so.6`.  Another way is to use `aria2`, `powerpill` or something else instead of `wget` - see `/etc/pacman.conf` `XferCommand` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Tips_and_tricks#Download_speeds

Comment: Tried symlinking to libnettle.so.7 but then I am greeted with other issues so I guessed it wont be that simple - thanks for the advice

I guess I'll have to try download and build aria2 from source and configure pacman to use that

Comment: just download packages from here https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/wget/, install them manually  `pacman -U packagename.tar.xz`

Comment: Thanks! All I had to do is just download wget manually and install it with pacman -U and the issue is resolved. While doing that I realized wget was missing in pacman cache and I also found this - `Sep 27    2017    wget.1.19.tar.gz` in my Downloads directory, which makes me think back then I must have installed wget manually and perhaps that was causing the messed up dependencies after the upgrade.. any thoughts?